# joomla virtuemart site loading issue

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, fastcgi, virtuemart

I have a Joomla site, integrated with virtuemart in it.
have almost 9,000 products.

it is not loading the site when i select a manufacturer from a module, which must list all products. Same problem is in the case of categories(have 2 categories).

**error is
FastCGI Error Number: 258 (0x80070102)**

when I have only 250 products, it was faster.

is there any way to overcome this issue otherthan changing the execution time?

Comment: add some more information about your server configurations.

Comment: PHP Version 5.2.13
System: Windows NT MHYELLOW-NT 5.2 build 3790
mysql: 5.0.51a

Comment: You could try to work out the SQL that is running and see if adding an index to the fields used in the join.

I've not run into this problem, but I am running only half the product you are in many more categories.

Comment: what version of VM is this. There were/are numerous backend queries that need some database indexes. Best to turn on debugging and paste the queries into PHPMyAdmin with Explain. Then add indexes accordingly

Answer (score 0):

With that number of products you should limit query and page the results... No one wants to see that number of results.

You'll be heavilly penalized by search engines also.

I really recommend a possibility of filtering products and paging them. You might have to tweak vm code and/or use plugins though